# Teams App registration issue : the bot name appears to contain default placeholder content

Tags: microsoft-teams, office-store

We are in a process to register our chatbot as Teams app in the store. We received some remarks from Microsoft validation team and I'm struggling with this one :

When the user is using personal bot, the bot name appears
to contain default placeholder content

Could anyone help me to identify where this bot name is set (in the manifest.json file I presume)

Thanks

Alex

See the manifest below :

```
{
"$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.0",
"version": "1.0.0",
"id": "c49de955-a3ee-4b8c-8fa0-4fdf540ccc8a",
"packageName": "com.askr",
"developer": {
    "name": "AskR",
    "websiteUrl": "https://askr.ai",
    "privacyUrl": "https://fr.askr.ai/cgu",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://fr.askr.ai/cgu"
},
"name": {
    "short": "AskR.ai",
    "full": "AskR.ai"
},
"description": {
    "short": "AskR.ai, your personal data assistant",
    "full": "AskR.ai, your personal data assistant"
},
"icons": {
    "outline": "askr32x32.png",
    "color": "askr192x192.png"
},
"accentColor": "#FF6633",
"staticTabs": [{
    "entityId": "askr",
    "name": "AskR.ai",
    "contentUrl": "https://askr.ai",
    "scopes": [
        "personal"
    ]
}],
"configurableTabs": [{
    "configurationUrl": "https://fr1.askr.ai/app",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "scopes": [
        "team"
    ]
}],
"bots": [{
    "botId": "c49de955-a3ee-4b8c-8fa0-4fdf540ccc8a",
    "needsChannelSelector": false,
    "isNotificationOnly": false,
    "scopes": [
        "personal"
    ]
}],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
"validDomains": ["*.askr.ai"]
```

}

Comment: Hi. Could you edit your question to include your manifest.json file? It might help people responding.

Comment: just added the manifest. thanks

Comment: @Alexaskr.ai Could you please contact teamsubm @ microsoft.com?